# Will installing Windows 10 affect Windows Live Mail?

Tags: email, windows-10-upgrade

I'm still on the fence about installing the new version of Windows. I currently have Windows 7 Premium and Windows Live Mail. Will installing Windows 10 render this email system obsolete?

Comment: Windows Live Mail is a web application.  It is completely independent of what's on your computer.  You access it with any browser.  Is the issue that you are using an email application on your computer (Like MS Outlook), and downloading messages, so you're concerned about the need to reconfigure?

Comment: @fixer1234 Windows Live Mail is a component of Windows Essentials http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-live/essentials , I remember seeing a reference to Windows Essentials being compatible with Windows 10 except for the OneDrive component which would be removed. I can't find the source at the moment so won't post an answer until I do.

Comment: @fixer1234 Live mail is not only web app, it is also a program you can install in Windows, similar to OE6 in functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows 10 [specifications](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications) contain the following statement:

> If you have Windows Live Essentials installed on your system, the OneDrive application is removed and replaced with the inbox version of OneDrive

I take that as implying that the other components of Windows Essentials including Windows Live Mail will continue to work.

Comment: The good news.  Even if its not compatible.  Unless the previous version of Windows is removed, by the author through the Cleanup Tool, the author will be able to uninstall Windows 10 with very little effort if it doesn't work.  Of course at the sametime Windows 10, if Windows Live Mail does not work, would have a replacement program.

Comment: I installed a 2011 version of Live Mail (15.4.3502) in Windows 10 preview, which I use today on W7, it was a stub installer I hung onto, it installed without issues and after a restart of the PC Windows installed some NetFramework dependencies, program works fine.

Comment: Indeed.  I install it and all the applications work, except for OneDrive, for obvious reasons.

Comment: I upgraded Windows 7 to 10. The Windows Live Mail application works fine. The settings, mail, calendar and contacts were all transferred correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Windows 10 from Windows 7 appears to totally knock out Windows Live Mail and all of its settings and stored emails.

The new `Mail` program does not seem to have any way to import stored messages from WLM. My solution was to install Firefox on Windows 7 and use its import/export tool, change over to Firefox.

Firefox settings and emails are preserved in the upgrade to Windows 10.