# Windows Live Mail lost with Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-10

After Windows 10 upgrade from Win 8.1 and Windows Live Mail install I loaded multiple email accounts, --everything appeared okay.  When going back into computer, I am now unable to access Windows Live Mail.   I am able to use Outlook for one mail address but want to be able to get back into Windows Live Mail.

Windows Live Mail does work perfectly when going to another computer but using
Windows 7.

Comment: I have in the past personally verified the last released version of `Windows Live Mail` does indeed work on Windows 10.  It sounds like you should simply install it again.  If that does not work or your settings are lost for some reason, I suggest you revert back to Windows 8.1, that your settings will be restored.  I have no idea what options you selected during the upgrade process, if you selected not to keep your personal files and application settings, then going back to Windows 8.1 likely will not be an viable option.

Answer (score 1):

In **Windows 10** you must install [Windows Live Essentials 2012](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/essentials) to get **Windows Live Mail**

[image]

[Related read](https://superuser.com/questions/937710/will-installing-windows-10-affect-windows-live-mail)

Comment: I am going to guess that the Windows 10 installer might have "removed" the application for compatibility reasons.  Just because it was "removed" does not make it actually not compatible (where it isn't usable) with Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes Windows 10 has been reported to remove Windows Live essentials but it has also been suggested that it can easily be reinstalled

Comment: I remember installing it and verifying that it worked.  I just took a guess its removed because the correct/incorrect assumption by Microsoft that it is redundant.